# Перевод из XMLHttpRequest в HttpClient (ts)

Tags: typescript, request, xmlhttprequest

Всем доброго времени суток!
Имеется код написанный на typescript, в нём формируется запрос и отправляется на сервер. На сервере формируется файл, преобразуется в байты и отправляется обратно. На фронте этот файл собирается и скачивается.

Есть следующий код запроса:

```typescript
return new Observable(obs => {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", url, true);
  oReq.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    obs.next(byteArray);
  };
  oReq.send();
});
```

Код полностью рабочий, работает на ура, всё отлично, но хотелось бы избавиться от XMLHttpRequest в пользу HttpClient. Пытался провернуть подобным образом:

```typescript
this.http.post<any>(url, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'), responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).subscribe({
  next: (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
});
```

Увы но выдаёт следующее сообщение: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

Comment: fetch() лучшая замена для XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2):

У вас в запросе вместо тела идут `httpOptions`.

В [документации](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) видно, что метод `post` принимает в себя аргументы:

```
this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

Если вам просто нужно отправить пустое тело, то запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
this.http.post<any>(url, {}, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'), responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error: any) => {
    console.error('error', error);
  });
```